# Ruby - create array by multiplying set of occurrences

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to create an array of size of 100 such that the values will appear X number of occurrences defined in another array.

So the below arrays:

```
arr1 = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6']
arr2 = [5, 5, 10, 10, 20, 50]
```

Will create a new array that contains 5 times the value `'text1'`, 50 times the value `'text6'`, etc.

Comment: Do you want sub arrays containing the strings or one flat array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one

```
arr1.zip(arr2).flat_map { |s, n| Array.new(n) { s } }
```

I first pair each string with its integer, then iterate over these pairs and create an array of n times string s. `flat_map` instead of simple `map` does the trick to not have a multidimensional array.

Comment: Just to point out the equivalence of `zip` and `transpose` when the two arrays are the same size, this could be written `[arr1, arr2].transpose.flat_map....`.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland ^_^

Comment: Depending on what OP wants, `Array.new(n){s}` might be preferable.

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
arr1.zip(arr2).map {|s,x| [s]*x}
```

Which will produce an array with a subarrays `[[s,s,s..],[s2,s2,s2...]]`.   If you don't want each string to be in a separate sub array:

```
arr1.zip(arr2).flat_map {|s,x| [s]*x}
```

As pointed out in comments, `zip` and `transpose` are equivalent so you can do:

```
[arr1, arr2].transpose.flat_map { |s,x| [s] * x }
```

Comment: Or `flat_map` instead of `map` and `flatten`.

Comment: Further to @muistooshort's point, if you believe that `flat_map` is here preferable to `flatten` (I suspect you do), why not just remove the `flatten` line? "Who suggested what" is irrelevant; just give the best answer you can, incorporation worthwhile suggestions made by others.

Answer (score 2):

**Array#cycle**

```
arr1.flat_map.with_index { |s,i| [s].cycle.take arr2[i] }
```

**Array#fill**

```
arr2.flat_map.with_index { |n,i| [].fill arr1[i], 0...n }
```

**Array#***

```
arr1.flat_map.with_index { |s,i| [s] * arr2[i] }
```

**Array#insert**

```
arr1.map.with_index { |s,i| [].insert 0, [s] * arr2[i] }.flatten
```